# Is there a way to find specific letters in a listbox in Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, listboxitem, verify

This is my first question on StackOverflow. It might not be up to the standards but just a basic query. Can I check for specific letters in a Listbox in Tkinter as the title states?

My code:

```
task_index = tasks_list.curselection()
selected_task = tasks_list.get(task_index) + "(Done)"

    for task in tasks_list.curselection():
        tasks_list.delete(task)
        tasks_list.insert(task_index, selected_task)
```

I want to check if (Done) is already present in the list item and if it is, print something like "error". Hope someone can help!

Comment: The posted code seems nothing related to your question.

Comment: I want the for loop to occur only if there is no "(Done)" it already. Hope it makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get what you want.

Comment: So, the thing is that there is a task in the listbox. But using a button, you can mark it done (that is basically editing the task to say the original task name + (Done)). This will tell the user that they finished that task. But I want to create a check that you can only mark the task done if the task is original and is not already marked.  Hope you understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the selected tasks, check whether the task ends with '(Done)'. If not, mark the task done by adding '(Done)' to the task:

```py
# assume mark_done() is executed when a button is clicked
# to mark selected tasks done
def mark_done():
    DONE_MARKER = '(Done)'
    for idx in tasks_list.curselection():
        task = tasks_list.get(idx)
        if not task.endswith(DONE_MARKER):
            # mark the task done
            tasks_list.delete(idx)
            tasks_list.insert(idx, f'{task} {DONE_MARKER}')
        else:
            print(f'"{task[:-len(DONE_MARKER)-1]}" already done')
```

Comment: Well, seems like a solution similar to what I came up with later!